# How to edit creation date of MP4 files?

Tags: python, date, metadata, mp4, exiftool

Currently, I'm working on a python3 script that helps me sort the Google Photos takeout files. The Takeout service for Google Photos actually strips all the metadata of an image/video into a separate JSON file.

This script that I'm working on helps me to merge the timestamp present in the JSON file into its subsequent photo or video. In order to achieve this, I'm currently using - **ExifTool by Phil Harvey**, which is a Perl executable. I call this tool in a subprocess to edit the Date tags in EXIF/Metadata.

This process is quite hefty and is taking a large amount of time. Then I realised that most of my photos are JPG and videos are MP4, it is very easy to edit Exif data of JPG files in python using some of the libraries present & for the lesser proportion of photos like PNG I can use exiftool.

This has drastically improved the runtime of my script. Now I want to know that is there any way to edit the creation dates of MP4 files natively in python which can theoretically execute faster than the subprocess method.

Please help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Google Photos does *not* strip away any metadata from files uploaded.  It gives you a copy of that data in the json which includes any changes you made on the website.  Changes made on the website are not embedded in the file and this is the only reason you want to do something like this.

Comment: As to the  run time, it sounds like you are running exiftool once for each file, which is [Exiftool Common Mistake #3](https://exiftool.org/mistakes.html#M3).  Exiftool's biggest performance hit is the startup time and running it once for each file can significantly increase the run time.  You should look into the [`-stay_open` option](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#stay_open-FLAG) where you start it and pass a text file to it with the `-@` option.  You then keep appending new commands to the text file which exiftool will then process.

Comment: Ofcourse, Metadata is still intact with the video files. Data like Device and Date captured as there. But I don't know most the videos have their dates 5:30 hrs less than my actual time zone (changed from IST to UTC). That is the reason why I want to batch edit the dates of MP4.

Comment: And for the Stay open option, I will try. Thanks!!!

Comment: The Quicktime standard for integer based time stamps (`CreateDate`, `ModifyDate`, `Media*Date`, `Track*Date`, but not `CreationDate` or `DateTimeOriginal`) is that they are supposed to be in UTC.  See the fourth paragraph on the [Exiftool Quicktime tags page](https://exiftool.org/TagNames/QuickTime.html). Windows and Mac OSs understand this and will automatically adjust the time from UTC to the local time of the computer.  Unfortunately, last I checked Adobe programs do **not** follow the spec and treat the time stamps as local time instead of UTC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not too familiar with it, but ffmpeg seems like an option for just the mp4's.

```
cmd = 'ffmpeg -i "file.mp4" -codec copy -metadata timestamp="new_time_here" "output.mp4"'
subprocess.call(shlex.split(cmd))
```

modified from:
https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/3yotj2/comment/cyfiyb7/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3